# magento 2 layered navigation count change every time

Tags: php, magento, magento2

When I am on the products page the products in the filter is displayed randomly

I try to reindex all my products category with

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

and flush my cache

```
bin/magento cache:flush
```

in my templete list.phtml I will search in my database the products with this code

```
$_productCollection = $block->getLoadedProductCollection()->clear()->addAttributeToSort('name', 'ASC');
$_helper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output');
$objectManager= \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$eavConfig= $objectManager->create('\Magento\Eav\Model\Config');
$attribute = $eavConfig->getAttribute('catalog_product', 'code_fini_mat');
$options = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions();
```

Comment: you mean to say it show random count?

Comment: yes the number is random

Comment: Can you verify it show properly in admin?